# C# Array Length Update

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, loops

I am solving the problem from this link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks (I added the link for more details if my explanation wasn't enough or wasn't quite clear.)

The point here from the exercise that I in the first I give a (int) number of sticks that I will use in the operation. the second line I enter the sticks length. So I must find the smallest stick(k), then subtract it from the rest of the sticks, then make the program print the number of total sticks that I have cut. So if the stick was cut before or its original value is 0 I have to remove it and don't count it. Then this should repeat over to redefine the value of the k because the min array value will be changed because all the sticks are cutted.

Here is my code that I used:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] userinput = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] arr = new int[n];
arr = Array.ConvertAll(userinput, Int32.Parse);
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    arr = arr.Where(s => s != '0').ToArray();
    int k = arr.Min();
    arr[i] -= k;
    Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

The problem is it keeps printing the n value, which is the array's original size, it doesn't modify after the removing of the 0. So how can I fix it to just print the number of cutted sticks and when the all sticks is 0 so break?

I'm sorry for my English and if my explanation is a bit hard, but I am just new to C#.

Comment: The char '0' is not the integer 0

Comment: @Steve even if i did it 0 not '0' still doesn't work

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: 6 //the first line
5 4 4 2 2 8 // the array values

Comment: And what should be the expected output of this input?

Comment: 6
4
2
1   this should be the expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code as you expected and tested.

Note: I just reused all the variable names and naming conventions as you did which can be refactored further.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] userinput = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            arr = Array.ConvertAll(userinput, Int32.Parse);
            CutTheStick(arr);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void CutTheStick(int[] arr)
        {
            arr = arr.Where(s => s != 0).ToArray();

            if (arr.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
                int k = arr.Min();

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] -= k;
                }

                CutTheStick(arr);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you had web/winForm based application, remove the `static` keyword accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Worked Perfectly and flawlessly !

Comment: @OmarAlaa Yes, it's well tested :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an evident error in your code. The char '0' is not the integer 0. The automatic conversion between char and int allows this code to compile and run but you are not testing correctly your inputs

For example

```
int[] arr = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4};

if(arr[0] == '0')
    Console.WriteLine("Is Zero");
```

will never print "Is Zero", while

```
int[] arr = new int[] {48,1,2,3,4};

if(arr[0] == '0')
    Console.WriteLine("Is Zero");
```

will print "Is Zero" because the integer value of the char '0' is 48.

Now to give a solution to your problem I could post this code

```
int cutCount = 1;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] userinput = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(userinput, Int32.Parse);

// Loop until we finish to empty the array
while (true)
{
    // remove any zero present in the array
    arr = arr.Where(s => s != 0).ToArray();

    // If we don't have any more elements we have finished
    if(arr.Length == 0) 
        break;

    // find the lowest value
    int k = arr.Min();

    // Start a loop to subtract the lowest value to all elements
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        arr[i] -= k;

    // Just some print to let us follow the evolution of the array elements
    Console.WriteLine($"After cut {cutCount} the array length is {arr.Length}");
    Console.Write("Array is composed of: ");
    foreach(int x in arr)
        Console.Write(x + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But please study it carefully because otherwise my solution is no help for you in future programming tasks

Comment: in my code there must be a zero. because i minus the minimum int in the array which already exists.

Comment: A much simple operator would be `% 2 == 0` to check if its **[even or odd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).**

Comment: Console.WriteLine($"After cut {cutCount} the array length is {arr.Length}"); can you please explain to me this line ?

Comment: I doubt the solution because to empty the array you have to resize the array. In C# only list can do it.